# Proof writing involving set theory operations: (A ∩ A') ∩ (B ∩ B') ∩ ( P (C) ∩ (P(C))') ∩ ((D x A)∩(DxA)') = ∅

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

**Prove:** (A ∩ A') ∩ (B ∩ B') ∩ ( P (C) ∩ (P(C))') ∩ ((D x A)∩(DxA)') =∅

Suppose by contradiction, (A ∩ A') ∩ (B ∩ B') ∩ ( P (C) ∩ (P(C))') ∩ ((D x A) ∩ (D x A)') ≠∅.

So then, ∃x ∈ U : x ∈ (A ∩ A') ∩ (B ∩ B') ∩ ( P (C) ∩ (P(C))' ) ∩ ((D x A) ∩ (D x A)')

Then we have, x ∈ (A ∩ A') ∧ x ∈ (B ∩ B') ∧ x ∈( P (C) ∩ (P(C))' ) ∧ x ∈ ((D x A) ∩ (D x A)')

Then, x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ A ∧ x ∈ B ∧ x ∉ B ∧ x ∈ P(C) ∧ x ∉ P(C) ∧ x ∈ (D x A) ∧ x ∉ (D x A)

Thus, contradiction x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ A .... which implies x ∈ ∅

Therefore, (A ∩ A') ∩ (B ∩ B') ∩ ( P (C) ∩ (P(C))') ∩ ((D x A)∩(D x A)') =∅

Is this correct? Another way to prove this? Tips for a better proof writing?

Comment: Who on earth decided that this kind of nonsense has a useful place in a maths course!

Comment: I don't know but yeah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s correct, but you can shorten it considerably:

> Suppose that $x$ is an element of the lefthand side. Then in particular $x\in A\cap A'$, so $x\in A$ and $x\in A'$. But then $x\in A$ and $x\notin A$, which is absurd. Thus, no such $x$ exists, and the lefthand side must be empty.